# Error SP MySql Workbench 1064 - Missing 'semicolon'

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, mysql-workbench

Soy un poco nuevo el mundo de MySQL y estoy tratando de construir el siguiente Store Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TablaPivote()
BEGIN
    SELECT t.fecha, 
        SUM(cod='513') as '513',
        SUM(cod='514') as '514',
        SUM(cod='515') as '515'
    FROM(
            SELECT e.timestamp as fecha, e.signature as cod, COUNT(e.timestamp) as Contador 
            FROM event e 
            group by e.timestamp,e.signature
        ) AS t
    GROUP BY t.fecha
END
```

Pero me arroja el error 1064 diciendo que es cerca del 'END' y marca en t.fecha después de GROUP BY 'SYNTAXIS ERROR: Missing **semicolon**', pero al ejecutar la consulta sola, ejecuta perfectamente.

Alguno tiene una idea de lo que estoy haciendo mal o que me falta en el SP para que funcione?

Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda y comentarios!

Saludos

Comment: Debería terminar así: `GROUP BY t.fecha;`  ... punto y coma antes del `END`. Ver el apartado [*24.1 Defining Stored Programs*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html) en el Manual de Referencia.

Comment: Hola Cedano, ya lo hice antes y aún sigue sin funcionar, voy a intentarlo a la vieja escuela con Delimiter y desde Cero. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Si no funciona puede ser un problema con los delimitadores. Lo que sí es claro según el Manual de Ref. es que la sentencia debe terminar siempre por `;`, de hecho, el error te dice eso, que falta el punto y coma (semicolon).

Comment: Claro, pero lo voy hacer desde el principio y te cuento cual fue el resultado

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de realizar el SP desde el principio y cambié los el delimiter por '$$' y añadí el ; que @A. Cedano acaba de recomendar y efectivamente funcionó.

Nota: Adjunto el SP por si alguien presenta el mismo problema

Saludos.

```
USE `xx`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `TablaPivote`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `xx`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `TablaPivote` ()
BEGIN
    SELECT t.fecha, 
        SUM(cod='513') as '513',
        SUM(cod='514') as '514',
        SUM(cod='515') as '515'
    FROM(
            SELECT e.timestamp as fecha, e.signature as cod, COUNT(e.timestamp) as Contador 
            FROM event e 
            group by e.timestamp,e.signature
        ) AS t
    GROUP BY t.fecha;
END$$
```